# How many characters can I store in an ID3v2 comment?

Tags: audio, id3, id3-tag

I'm trying to find some definite information on the length comment area in ID3v2 tags.   In the [spec](http://www.id3.org/id3v2.3.0#head-31c41e8642534f1854246708af84f7d2c8d39684) it doesn't mention anything concrete(or I just don't understand it).

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final string size is determined by the frame size. Look up the definition of the [frame header](http://www.id3.org/id3v2.3.0#head-1a37d4a15deafc294208ccfde950f77e47000bca); it includes a "size" field. Everything else either has a definite size or is a terminated string, so by the time you get to the final text field, there's no more ambiguity.

Comment: So in the end "as you like" :-)

Comment: @xanatos: I guess the limit is the frame size, which is a 32-bit integer :-) (Minus 10 for the header and minus the other fields, of course.)